# Showing hidden form field when specific URL is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is populated dynamically using URL parameters. The problem is that one of the parameters in the URL selects an option in a dropdown, which should then `show` a field. That field is not showing on page load.

Note that I have a simple check on page load that should show the field, so I am wondering if URL parameters are passed after the `document.ready` state.

Here is the URL that I am using:
https://donate.globaltc.org/#designation=3&missionary=Jerry%20Nance

The dropdown is selecting the correct option.

Here is my JS:

```
// Show or hide field
var $missionary = $('.missionary');
    var $designation = $('#designation');
    var $project = $('.project');

    if($designation.val() != 3){
        $missionary.hide();    
    } else {
        $missionary.show();    
    }
// Handle URL parameters
var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
    for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
        var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
        document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
    }
```

HTML Form:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">How would you like this gift to be designated?</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="designation" name="designation">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Most Urgent Need</option>
   <option value="3">A Global Team Member</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 missionary">
   <label for="missionary">Name of Team Member</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="missionary" name="missionary">
 </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you call the show/hide function again after the parameter handler?

Comment: @m69 I tried that but it did not work. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in my code, but it did not solve my issue. The error:

```
if($designation.val() != 3){ //Should be string not int
```

Here is the hacky way that I made this work.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if($designation.val() == '3'){
        $missionary.show();    
    } else {
        $missionary.hide();       
    }
}, 100);
```

I would still like a more definitive answer on why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var designationValue = parseInt($designation.val(), 10);` to figure out what the int value of the field is before using it in your if statement.

Documentation for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: I know that it is `3` because I am using the URL parameter to change the dropdown, which is working.